# is it possible to extract the formula for a spline function in Java?

Tags: java, math, polynomial-math, numerical-analysis

Is there any way to describe the [PolynomialSplineFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialSplineFunction.html#PolynomialSplineFunction(double[],%20org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.polynomials.PolynomialFunction[])), or any other spline function in Java, by a single formula [y = f(x)]?

Comment: what you provided in the link *is* the functional implementation of PolynomialSplines, in Java - what else do you expect from it? You construct the spline by providing the knots etc, and then you specify the parameter, and receive the resulting value from the function call... in a functional y = f(x) way, that is.

Comment: @vaxquis I want to export the function, say to string or text file. Not as a serialized Object, but in a regular mathematical formula/representation.

Answer (score 2):

Java has no particular influence.

The formula depends on the actual polynomials used in the various intervals. Typically, cubic polynomials (order 3) are used.

It isn't a single formula; you have to select the polynomial assigned to a particular x-interval, and then you have the usual polynomial expression: `f(x) = ax³ + bx² + cx + d`

Comment: I would write the `f(x)` part as `ax³ + bx² + cx + d` just not to give the impression that you can directly copy and paste it in Java. The `^` vs. `Math.pow`/`x*x*x` question gets asked quite often on SO...

Comment: @laune It's not possible to represent a B-Spline as a sum? [example](http://imgur.com/N4xuinj)

Comment: This is the recursion formula for the polynomials for the intervals. The terms are added (more precisely, linear combinations), but there's no overall "sum" in the same quality as a Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

General spline functions have the formula

y=a+b*x+sum(k=0 to n) c_k*max(0,x-x_k)^3

The usefulness of this formula, especially in terms of numerical stability, might be doubtful. There is a rising amount of cancellations involved for x > x_k with rising k. There might be potential for optimization in this respect with including terms d_k*max(0,x_k-x)^3, and I'm pretty sure there are experimental and perhaps also theoretical studies in that directions somewhere out there.